# Uploading 500000 records using load data InFile in CI but sometimes not all records inserted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

I am uploading 500 000 records using load data InFile in CI but sometime all record inserted or sometime thousand records not inserted in same csv file.

Controller

```
public function upload_csv_test()
{
    $adminid = $this->session->userdata('aid');
    if(empty($adminid))
    {
        redirect('admin/index');
    }
    else
    { 
        $file_path = "/var/www/html/asset/test_csv/5Lac.csv";
        $sub = $this->Admin_model->add_csv_data($file_path);      
    } 
}
```

Model

```
public function add_csv_data($file_path)
{   

    $this->db->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$file_path."' 
    INTO TABLE test_csv     
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
    IGNORE 1 LINES
    (cid,latitude,longitude,Email,Personal_FirstName)
    ");

}
```

Comment: May be due to Script execution time, Try to Increase your execution time in php.ini file

Comment: it takes 30 to 40 seconds approx so, I think not need to Increase execution time .

Comment: Do it in batches of 10k-25k. Check for errors after each batch insert and log the errors. This way you will know which data could not make it into your database and why.

Comment: Have you validated the file, to make sure it's formatted correctly? https://csvlint.io/

Comment: Are you sure none are duplicate?

Comment: it's formatted file,sometime same file does not inserted all data into DB or sometime all data inserted into DB.

Comment: in `database.php` turn on `db_debug` and read CI docs on how to use transactions

Answer (score 0):

That functionality doesn't insert any data if the database would throw an error. Usually it is when a column has the wrong format like a date or decimal numbers.

If you can detect one file on which it fails, take it, split it in smaller batches and look at the values. You could even transform it into a normal insert-command and test it with the failing data.
Good luck!